# Why can't I have a method with the same name as a member type?

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is some code that fails in VS2012:

```
class A;

class B
{
    bool A();
    A member; // Error: function B::A is not a type name
};
```

Why doesn't this work? Obviously I'm trying to create a member of type `A`, not of type `B:A()` (which isn't a type, as the compiler correctly points out). Is there some way around this without changing the names of either `B:A()` or `class A`? Can I explicitly tell the compiler that I want `member` to be of type `class A`?

Comment: Are you trying to drive readers of your code mad? There are more efficient ways to do that.

Comment: @n.m. `A()` might be a getter function for a pointer to an instance of `A` to which the instance of `B` belongs, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails because they share a namespace. C++ cannot, in general distinguish types and functions based on context (is `A()` a constructor or a function call). You can make it explicit which one you refer to, e.g.

```
class A;

class B
{
    bool A();
    ::A member;
};
```

Comment: What exactly does the `::` tell the compiler in this case? That it's an object, not a function?

Comment: using namespace global, not B::

Comment: The `::` tells the compiler to look in the global scope. Similarly `B::A` would tell it look for A in the scope of class `B`.

Comment: @ausairman: `::name` tells the compiler to look in the global namespace for `name` instead of the local one.

Comment: Let's hope that A isn't really in the global namespace, though.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible, you just need to make clear that you want to use the *class* `A`:

```
class A;

class B
{
    bool A();
    class A member;
};
```

Comment: I think this is not what OP asked about, the method is "A" and member is "member"

Comment: @computer: OP wants to have a member `member` which is of type `class A`. The method is still `A`, the member is still `member`.

Comment: ah, OK this is it, true. I thought he wants something else, the title suggest method "m" and member with same "m" name